# JanusGraph query exception:org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Could not find type for id

Tags: janusgraph

I can login and connect the tinkerpop server successfully, but when i execute a gremlin, there come out one strange exception：org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Could not find type for id: 137481, i use g.V(137481), there also throws an exception, but when i execute g.V(137481).valueMap(true), it return an node, here is the gremlin 
 execution result:

```
[root@docker9 janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2]# bin/gremlin.sh
           \,,,/
           (o o)
  -----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
  plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
  plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
  plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
  SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
  SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
  09:51:06 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
  plugin activated: tinkerpop.spark
  plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
  gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
  ==>Configured cdh-slave1/192.168.66.149:8182-[f699751a-c046-472f-8d84-a22a7897b241]
  gremlin> :remote console
  ==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [cdh-slave1/192.168.66.149:8182]-[f699751a-c046-472f-8d84-a22a7897b241] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
  gremlin> g
  ==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[cassandrathrift:[192.168.66.149]], standard]

gremlin> g.V(137481).valueMap()
==>{}
gremlin> g.V(137481)
Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: Could not find type for id: 137481. Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.V(137481).valueMap(true)
==>{id=137481, label=vertex}
```

> **I'm sure that the vertex who's 'uri'='/0/85' is already exists!**

```
gremlin> g.V().has('uri','/0/85').valueMap()
Could not find type for id: 137481
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Could not find type for id: 137481
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:175)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:99)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:166)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:478)
```

Comment: Is there a full, nested exception in the `gremlin-server.log`? Does `g.V().has('uri','/0/85').valueMap(true)` throw the same error? If not, what is the result?

Comment: I'am very greatful for you to answer my question. But g.V().has('uri','/0/85').valueMap(true)  does not throw any error, here is the result: gremlin> g.V(137481).valueMap(true)
==>{id=137481, label=vertex}

Comment: I don't know why this exception is going out. One day, It suddenly appeared. Is there some vertex that i deleted then cause this happen? Or there some thing i don't know?

Comment: Did you find the cause/solution for this ? I am getting the same error

Comment: same error happens also to me, any solution yet ?

Comment: maybe this question was caused by the index，check if this vertex still exists in the MixedIndex or CompositeIndex

Answer (score 1):

It happens if multiple instances of Gremlin Server are running
because a Gremlin Server was not shutdown or killed properly.
It can happen because the VM on which Gremlin Server is running might have restarted.

The solution is login to the Gremlin Console and run your commands based on your backend; in my case it's Cassandra and ElasticSearch

So, I ran

**Method 1**

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session

:remote console session
```

or

```java
graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-cql-es.properties');

g=graph.traversal()
```

and if you are running containers then your command should be similar to this

```java
graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties');

g=graph.traversal()
```

Now, after running those you can run

```java
mgmt = graph.openManagement()

mgmt.getOpenInstances()
```

it will display all the instances

eg

```
ac12000231-a9ffbcbb0e921

ac12000230-a9ffbcbb0e921(current)
```

Except that current instance, you should close the other instances

```java
mgmt.forceCloseInstance('ac12000231-a9ffbcbb0e921')
```

After closing all the instances commit the changes

```java
mgmt.commit()
```

Now restart your Gremlin Server and run your query, and it should work

**Method 2**

If the problem persists, just kill your Gremlin Server and start it again few times and it should work.

Another reason why this happens is if the data is not restored properly. If you are using a cluster take the backup on all the nodes then restore on your destination node or nodes.

I used `nodetool` for backup and `sstableloader` for restoring data .

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to put code blocks in backticks which makes it much easier to spot the code from the text.

Comment: Thanks for trying to make the edits. You need to use the back-tick character ` to highlight code not the double quote ". I went ahead and completed the edits.